# How to optimize the performance of the VBA code?

Tags: excel, vba

I have troubles in running the following codes. Basically the idea is to sort the list and copy the unique records to another sheet. But due to the large number of records (160000 rows). My code always hanged and could not stop calculation.

```
Columns("A:A").Insert Shift:=xlToRight
Range("A1").Value = "Reference2"
Range("A2").Formula = "=B2&F2&N2"
Range("A2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("A2:A160000")

Range("N1").Value = "Day"

Range("N2").Formula = "=DAY(G2)"
Range("N2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("N2:N160000")

Columns("A:N").Select
Selection.Sort Key1:=Range("N2"), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlGuess, _
OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, _
DataOption1:=xlSortNormal

Columns("A:N").Select
Selection.Sort Key1:=Range("F2"), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlGuess, _
OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, _
DataOption1:=xlSortNormal

Columns("A:N").Select
Selection.Sort Key1:=Range("B2"), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlGuess, _
OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, _
DataOption1:=xlSortNormal


Sheets("Fairbanks Data").Range("A1:N" & Range("B1").End(xlDown).Row).Select
Selection.Copy

Sheets("Fairbanks Data(Edited)").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
'my code always stopped at here and did the calculation

Sheets("Fairbanks Data").Delete

Sheets("Fairbanks Data(Edited)").Range("A1:A160000").AdvancedFilter     Action:=xlFilterCopy, CopyToRange:=Sheets("Step1Raw").Range("A2"), Unique:=True
```

Is that any way I can improve the speed? Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few Rules for VBA with what you can make your code faster.

---

**Rule #1. Don't Copy and Paste**

The Copy and Paste (or **PasteSpecial**) functions are slow. It is about 25 times faster to use the following to copy and paste values.

```
Range("A1:Z100").value = Range("A101:Z200").value
```

If you are doing it this way your Code will Probably work. There is maybe a problem with the Mamory if your are doing this on so many Rows.

---

**Rule #2. Calculation**

Normally, Excel will recalculate a cell or a range of cells when that cell's or range's precedents have changed.  This may  cause your workbook to recalculate too often, which will slow down performance.  You can prevent Excel from recalculating the workbook by using the statement:

```
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
```

At the end of your code, you can set the calculation mode back to automatic with the statement:

```
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
```

Remember, though, that when the calculation mode is **xlCalculationManual**, Excel doesn't update values in cells.  If your macro relies on an updated cell value, you must force a Calculate event, with the .Calculate method like `Worksheets(1).Calculate`.

---

**Rule #3. ScreenUpdating**

The Other Speed Problem with VBA is, every time VBA writes data to the worksheet it refreshes the screen image that you see. Refreshing the image is a considerable drag on performance. The following command turns off screen updates.

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = FALSE
```

At the end of the macro use the following command to turn screen updates back on.

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = TRUE
```

Answer (score 2):

I have these two subs which I tend to put before and after any code I run.

```
' 01.
Sub deaktiver()
  Application.EnableEvents = False
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  Application.DisplayStatusBar = False
  Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
  ' ActiveSheet.DisplayPageBreaks = True 'note this is a sheet-level setting
End Sub
' 02.
Sub reaktiver()
  Application.EnableEvents = True
  Application.ScreenUpdating = True
  Application.DisplayStatusBar = True
  Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
  ' ActiveSheet.DisplayPageBreaks = True 'note this is a sheet-level setting
End Sub
```

Obviously you need to know, what the different settings do, as some of the settings will prevent calculations to happen or events to fire, as Moosli explained above.

Most (all?) of what's in the code above I found [here](http://blogs.office.com/2009/03/12/excel-vba-performance-coding-best-practices/), which also goes into quite a few other ways to make your code more efficient.