# When excel program runs, the program does not respond and shuts down

Tags: excel, vba

When comparing data in two worksheets, my macro has to do something if the data is the same. There are 7000 lines in the first worksheet and 4000 lines in the second.

I wrote two nested for loops and made comparisons.

There are 7000 * 4000 = 28.000.000 comparisons and Excel gives error when I run the program. How can I run the program.

```
Dim sheet2RowCount As Long
Dim sheet1RowCount As Long
Dim Owner1FName As String
Dim OwnerName As String
Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long

sheet1RowCount = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Worksheets("Sheet1").Columns(1))
sheet2RowCount = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Worksheets("APN'i buraya tasi").Columns(2))

Dim counter As Long
counter = 0
For i = 2 To sheet1RowCount
    OwnerfullName = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 27).Value + " " + Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 28).Value
    mailAddress = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 3).Value
    propertyAddress= Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 2).Value
    
    For j = 2 To sheet2RowCount
    
        OwnerfullName2 = Worksheets("APN'i buraya tasi").Cells(j, 2).Value
        mailAddress2 = Worksheets("APN'i buraya tasi").Cells(j, 7).Value
        propertyAddress2 = Worksheets("APN'i buraya tasi").Cells(j, 3).Value
        
        If (OwnerfullName=OwnerfullName2) Then
            counter = counter + 1
        End If
    
    Next j
Next i
```

Comment: So you are trying to count how many times does each name of first page appear in cells in second page? Why not using a single COUNTIF for each name?

Comment: What I am trying to do is find the name on the first page and the same names on the second page, but there is a lot of data and the program is closing. How can I avoid this

Comment: Probably you will need to change the code to optimize. Did you debug? At what moment does it crash? execute it with F8 and debug it

Comment: Do this makes a difference if you call it inside the busy loop? `If j mod 500 = 0 Then DoEvents` Also I have never benchmarked but should you use `Dim ws as Worksheet | set ws = Worksheets("mysheetname") | ws.cells(iRow, iCol) ` variable reference in a loop to make it at least look optimized.

Comment: I get the right results when I shrink the numbers in the loops but i need all

Comment: You could have a look at the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28208246/4497791), to get some general guidelines on how to make the code run more efficiently. I think your best bet here is to restructure your code though, as others have mentioned.

Comment: how can i compare less? I have to compare all of them one by one so that the names are the same

Comment: Have you considered adding `DoEvents` in the loop, so that Excel remembers to let Windows know *"Yes, I'm still alive"*

Comment: No I don't know how to do it, can you give me an example?

Comment: @BERKAYKÜÇÜK Literally, just stick the line `DoEvents` inside your loop somewhere.  (Of course, [the `DoEvents` function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/doevents-function) is slow, so it's better to call it every 100 loops or something, instead of *every* loop)

Answer (score 0):

Okay, let's shrink your second loop, *massively*, using `WorksheetFunction.CountIf` and `WorksheetFunction.Match` (Or, rather, `Application.Match`, which will return the error value as a `Variant` instead of throwing an error).  First, we can use `WorksheetFunction.CountIf` to work out how many times the second loop needs to run (if any).  Next, we can use `WorksheetFunction.Match` to *skip straight to the row we need*, bypassing the ones we don't.

We will also be calling [the `DoEvents` function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/doevents-function) every 5 seconds, to remind Windows that the application is running, and has not frozen or crashed on us.

(N.B. due to your aversion to using `COUNTIF` / `COUNTIFS`, I am assuming that there might be some other code running where you currently have the `counter = counter + 1`.  Because, if not, then what's the point of the `mailAddress`, `mailAddress2`, `propertyAddress` and `propertyAddress2` variables?)

```
Dim OwnerFullName AS String, OwnerFullName2 AS String
Dim MailAddress AS String, MailAddress2 AS String
Dim PropertyAddress AS String, PropertyAddress2 AS String

Dim ws1 AS Worksheet, ws2 AS Worksheet
Dim sheet1RowCount As Long, sheet2RowCount As Long

Dim i AS Long, counter AS Long
Dim MatchRow AS Variant, EventsLastDone AS Single

Set ws1 = Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set ws2 = Worksheets("APN'i buraya tasi")

sheet1RowCount = WorksheetFunction.CountA(ws1.Columns(1))
sheet2RowCount = WorksheetFunction.CountA(ws2.Columns(1))

counter = 0
EventsLastDone = Timer

For i = 2 To Sheet1RowCount
    Application.StatusBar = "Row " & cstr(i-1) & " of " & cstr(Sheet1RowCount-1)

    OwnerFullName = ws1.Cells(i,27).Value & " " & ws1.Cells(i, 28).Value
    mailAddress = ws1.Cells(i,3).Value
    propertyAddress = ws1.Cells(i,2).Value

    'Only Loop if there are matches
    If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(ws2.Columns(2),OwnerFullName) > 0 Then
        'Find First Match
        MatchRow = Application.Match(OwnerFullName,ws2.Columns(2),0)
        While MatchRow <= Sheet2RowCount
            OwnerFullName2 = ws2.Cells(MatchRow, 2).Value
            mailAddress2 = ws2.Cells(MatchRow, 7).Value
            propertyAddress2 = ws2.Cells(MatchRow, 3).Value
            
            counter = counter+1
            
            'Find the next Match
            MatchRow = Application.Match(OwnerFullName,ws2.Range(ws.Cells(MatchRow+1,2),ws.Cells(Sheet2RowCount+1,2)) ,0)
            If IsError(MatchRow) Then MatchRow = Sheet2RowCount+1 'Exit when there are no more matches
            
            If (EventsLastDone+86400-Timer) mod 86400 > 5 Then
                'Check in with Windows every 5 seconds
                DoEvents
                EventsLastDone = Timer
            End If
        Wend
        
        If (EventsLastDone+86400-Timer) mod 86400 > 5 Then
            'Check in with Windows every 5 seconds
            DoEvents
            EventsLastDone = Timer
        End If
    End If
Next i

Application.StatusBar = False

Set ws1 = Nothing
Set ws2 = Nothing
```

Basically, instead of running 7,000 sets of 4,000 comparisons (28,000,000 total), we will run 7,000 initial comparisons ("Are there any matches?"), and then anywhere from 0 to 4,000 *more* comparisons (1 for each Match).  This gives us anywhere between 7,000 and 11,000 comparisons total, or ***0.04%*** of the number of comparisons you were originally doing